# how to make bootstrap modal form take input of emails from a table when the corresponding button of the table row is clicked

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

So the issue I am having is that no matter what button I click from the table it just inputs the first email in the database. I want it to grab the email of the corresponding record of the button that was clicked, this is the table:-

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
      <thead> 
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th> 
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">EMAIL</th>
          <th scope="col">SUBJECT</th>
          <th scope="col">MESSAGE</th>
          <th scope="col">TIME</th>
          <th scope="col">Action</th>
          <!-- <th scope="col">status</th> -->
        </tr>
    </thead>

<?php
    $sql = "SELECT  id, name, email, subject, message, time FROM contact";
    $records = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    // $products = mysqli_fetch_array($records);

    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
      {
    ?>


 <form method="post">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $data['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['email']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['subject']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['message'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['time']; ?></td> 
    <td><a href="reply.php">reply</a></td>
    <td><button type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal"data-bs-whatever="<?php echo $data['email'];?>">Reply</button></td></form>
</tr>
```

above is the button that toggles the modal.
below is the modal itself

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
              <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="POST" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
                  <div class="row">
```

below is the input i am having problems with. and the last bit is the remaing part of the modal
remaining modal

Recipient:
                      ">

```
                <div class=" col-md-6 mb-3">
                  <label for="Email-Subject" class="col-form-label">Email-Subject:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject">
                </div>


                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
                </div>


                <div class=" col-md-6 mb-3">
                  <label for="attachment" class="col-form-label">Attachment</label>
                  <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file[]" multiple= "multiple" id="file">
                </div>
              </div>
              <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send mail</button>
              
            </form>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

this closes the while loop

```
<?php 
}
?>
```

this is the PHP mailer code

```
<?php
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
   
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = "foxyfox069@gmail.com";
        $mail->Password = "musa3310";
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->setFrom("foxyfox069@gmail.com");
        $mail->addAddress($_POST['email']);
        // $mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
        $mail->isHTML(true);    
        $mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $mail->Body = $_POST['message'];
        for ($i=0; $i <count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) ; $i++) { 
         
          $mail->addAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
        }
        try {
            $mail->send();
            echo 'Your message was sent successfully!';
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Your message could not be sent! PHPMailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
        }
      } 
    else {
        echo "There is a problem with the contact.html document!";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You can not nest a form into a table like that, that's invalid HTML. Either the form has to go around the whole table, or be contained within a single table cell.

Comment: sorry im new to this can you please explain more. what do you mean by "the form has to go around the whole table, or be contained within a single table cell. "

Comment: It either has to be `<form><table>...</table></form>`, or `<table><tr><td><form></form></td></tr></table>`. Putting it around the tbody for example, is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined modal for each row in while loop, so you need to keep unique id for all modal, other way you can define modal out of loop and add modal show event to define email address.